# Detect images and text in PDF using Google Vision(OCR)

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Does Google Vision API(OCR) support splitting images and text in a PDF? Currently, we are using google OCR with DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION(Java client) which is doing pdf to text. But if there are any images embedded in PDF, it's skipping them. Is there a possibility to extract/separate images in PDF along with text?

Comment: Maybe https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/drag-and-drop will have better results ?

Comment: No, did not work. It also skips images in pdf(extracts only text)

Comment: Wait, what you want to extract from the images embedded in the pdf?

Comment: There are images and text in PDF, I need images alone to be separated and save them in a directory.